# Can I use my old university email for signing up on arxiv?

Tags: arxiv

It has been a couple of years since I graduated from my institution, but can I sign up on arxiv using my university email? I want to submit a preprint of my paper

Comment: Did you read the terms&conditions of arxiv? what do they say?

Comment: They said that it is okay if there is an affiliation through an email address, but I am a former student with a permanant active email address. I wanted to know if it was okay to consider this as a case of active affiliation

Comment: In a comment you state " I have a permanant email address from my former institution, but I am currently an intern and working under a temporary email ID" are you an intern in the university? Not clear.

Additionally, *" this research is from my previous internship"* this is a big issue, are you sure you can publish intellectual work you performed during your previous internship?

Comment: Obviously, there is no intellectual property issue. My temporary email is from my internship at a different institution, and my university email is permanent and still active.

Comment: I think you are playing with words. An active email from an university is usually sufficient proof of being affiliated to an university. But in itself, the active email means 
nothing. If you are affiliated with an university, you will **for sure** have an active email, but the contrary is not true. 
Make your life easier: instead of asking random people in the internet, ask directly  your university if you can consider yourself still affiliated with them.

Answer (score 3):

A starting point is '*what's your affiliation with your (former) university*'

Whatever it is, whatever is applicable will determine whether the light is green or red.

- Is there any reason why you can't sign up with your current email(s)?
- Do you have adjunct or associate position or affiliated link to your university

[Extract: Arxiv policy note on email](https://info.arxiv.org/help/registerhelp.html)
*It is a violation of our policies to misrepresent your identity or organizational affiliation. Claimed affiliation should be current in the conventional sense: e.g., physical presence, funding, e-mail address, etc. Misrepresentation of identity or affiliation, for any reason, is possible grounds for immediate and permanent suspension.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have a permanant email address from my former institution, but I am currently an intern and working under a temporary email ID. In addition, this research is from my previous internship, so I cannot use this company's email. I saw that an active email address qualifies as a qualification of affiliation, so would it be alright to sign up, in your opinion?